# How can I edit/add to the 'url' inside an 'a' tag's onclick event using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have the below element on my web page:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.fxs.dev/quote/quote.aspx" onclick="javascript:window.location='http://www.fxs.dev/quote/quote.aspx?partnumber=526-NTE3031';" return="" false;="">Request Delivery Quote</a>
```

I would like to try and add querystrings to the 'url' in the "`onclick`" attribute of the element.
Is there a jquery function that allows me to do edit just the "URL" part of the `onclick` event. Or do i just have to write my own custom function to strip and edit the `onclick` event code?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the onclick attribute contains a string that's interpreted as Javascript code. I'm aware of only two things you can do with this; execute it as Javascript, or edit is as a String. The latter would mean you would have to strip the url from it and edit it manually, I'm afraid.

I don't quite see the reason to having a `window.location=` call as the only thing in the onclick of an anchor tag.. wouldn't that be what the href attribute is for? That's also much easier to edit with jQuery, using `.attr('href','http://example.com');`

Comment: good point...I do not know why it had to be the onclick event! This is a piece of old code i am working with, so I was trying to not break anything without knowing the reason :)